# Forming a committee from $4$ gentlemen and $4$ ladies with certain conditions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> From $4$ gentlemen and $4$ ladies a committee of $5$ is to be formed .
>   If the committee consists of $1$ president, $1$ vice president and $3$ secretaries.
>   What will be the number of ways of selecting the committee with at least $3$
>   women such that at least one women holds the post of president or vice-president?

I tried

Case $1$

$3W2M$

$\dbinom{4}{1}\times \dbinom{4}{1} \times \dbinom{3}{2} \times \dbinom{3}{1}=144 $

$+$

$\dbinom{4}{1}\times \dbinom{3}{1} \times \dbinom{2}{1} \times \dbinom{4}{2}=144 $

Case $2$

$4W1M$

$\dbinom{4}{1}\times \dbinom{3}{1} \times \dbinom{2}{2} \times \dbinom{3}{1}=36 $

$+$

$\dbinom{4}{1}\times \dbinom{4}{1} \times \dbinom{3}{3}=16 $

Total ways=$338$.

But the answer given is $512$.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: You have made mistakes in calculating your nCr, there are other logical errors too. At least correct the computational ones so that someone can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, there are numerous errors in your answer.

Pres-Veep . . . . . Secretaries

*W-W . . . . . . . . . 2W,1M or 1W-2M:* $\left[{4\choose1 }{3\choose 1}\right]\left[{2\choose2}{4\choose1} + {2\choose 1}{4\choose 2}\right]= 192$

*W-M or M-W . . . . 3W or 2W,1M:* $\left[2{4\choose1}{4\choose1}\right]\left[{3\choose 3}+{3\choose2}{3\choose1}\right]=320$

Answer (score 4):

Count the number of committees with $\color\red{3\text{ women}}$ and $\color\green{2\text{ men}}$:

$$\color\red{\binom43}\cdot\color\green{\binom42}\cdot\binom51\cdot\binom41\cdot\binom33=480$$

Subtract the number of committees where all $3$ women are secretaries:

$$\color\red{\binom43}\cdot\color\green{\binom42}\cdot\color\green{\binom21}\cdot\color\green{\binom11}\cdot\color\red{\binom33}=48$$

Add the number of committees with $\color\red{4\text{ women}}$ and $\color\green{1\text{ man}}$:

$$\color\red{\binom44}\cdot\color\green{\binom41}\cdot\binom51\cdot\binom41\cdot\binom33=80$$

Hence the number of committees is $480-48+80=512$.